Close graph theorem and derivative operator
Let $X=C([0,1])$  with the sup norm.
$A:D(A)⊂E→E; D(A)=C^1;Ax=x'$
I can show that A si closed:
Let $x_n→x$ in $E$ and $Ax_n→y$ in $E$. It is basic calculus to show that the uniform Convergence of derivative implies that
$x∈C^1$ and $y=Ax=x'$ . So then A is closed and by the close  graph theorem it is bounded (continues).
But if we choose:
$x_n=t^n⇒Ax_n=nt^{n-1}⇒‖Ax_n ‖ =n$ . So it is unbounded. What am I doing wrong ?

$A$ is not defined on a Banach space

It is about space and the topology you chose for this space (norm or inner product). If you are willing to go to Sobolev spaces (Banach spaces), for example, $A$ is a bounded operator from $H^1$ to $L^2$, but an unbounded operator from $L^2$ to $L^2$.

The closed graph theorem only applies if $D(A)$ is closed. This is not the case for your operator.
